# Converting int array to collections

Tags: java, arrays, collections

I'm learning Java step by step. Now I know up to arrays, and next is Collections.

As I'm learning based on projects, I noticed that most of programmers choose to use `Collections` rather than plain arrays to eliminate the loops and to make use of the predefined functions (like `sort` and much more). So, first I'm trying to convert an `int[]` into a `Collection`. But I get an error in the `foreach` loop...

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Coll {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Coll obj = new Coll();
        obj.op();
    }

    void op() {
        System.out.println("To convert Array to Collections");
        Scanner getinp = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the size of array : ");
        int siz = getinp.nextInt();
        int[] arry = new int[siz];
        System.out.println("Enter the values of elements");
        for (int i = 0; i < arry.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("arry[" + i + "] : ");
            arry[i] = getinp.nextInt();
        }

        List arrycoll = Arrays.asList(arry);
        for (String elem : arrycoll) {
            System.out.println(elem);
        }
    }
}
```

The error is in the following line:

```
for(String elem : arrycoll)
```

Pointing to `arrycoll`, it states:

```
required `String` but found `Object`
```

If I define the `arry` as `String` and store `String`s, it wouldn't be a error, but for `int` it's not working..

Comment: Use *generics*.. `List<Integer>`. Also, you are inserting an Integer and trying to get a String back..

Comment: `Arrays` actually support `sort`ing.

Comment: You can actually use the *foreach* syntax with plain arrays as well. And you can sort your arrays using `Arrays#sort(int[])` just as you'd use `Collections.sort(List)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given this message

> it states required String but found object

You are getting two important pieces of information. One, you are using `String` for elements of your `int[]`. And, two you have a raw type (so your Integer elements are being treated as Object elements).
Don't use [Raw Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html)! I'm pretty sure you wanted something like

```
List<Integer> arrycoll = Arrays.asList(arry);
for(Integer elem:arrycoll) { // <-- Integer, not String.
  System.out.println(elem);
}
```

**Edit**

Of course to work with a collection, you'll need an object. `int` has the `Integer` wrapper type, so you'll need to change

```
int[] arry=new int[siz];
```

to

```
Integer[] arry=new Integer[siz];
```

Comment: Now you will get this compiler error at: `Arrays.asList(arry)`. Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<int[]> to List<Integer>

Comment: thank you.. changing it to Integer arry from int arry works out and after making it as list, Collections.reverse(arrycoll) works fine.. But what is the diff b/w use of Integer and int.. From the start I thought integer is expansion and int is keyword for defining datatype in program.. @Elliott Frisch

Comment: @krnaveen14 No. `int` is a [primitive type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html). `Integer` is a wrapper class. The primitive types are a performance optimization. Also, the `Collection`(s) require Object instances.

Comment: The main difference is that Integers can be used as subclasses of Object, for example be stored in a list or map as generic parameters. The "Integer" *class* also provides additional methods for the int. While most of the time this is hidden due to auto-boxing, you can explicitly cast between int to Integer. Also, a major key difference is that Integer can have the value *null*.

Answer (score 0):

No problem!

1. Change List to List which will now staticky type the Objects in the list to integers (Badically, they are all treated as Integers)
2. Replace String with Integer, as now all the objects in the list are of type Integer (not String or anything else)

Answer (score 0):

> required `String` but found `Object`

In your for each loop, you are using String as type for element whereas arrycoll is list of raw List references whose type is Object.

```
List arrycoll
```

You've declared list of raw List references. You have to tell the compiler that they'll be `List<Integer> values`:

```
List<Integer> arrycoll
```

and

1. use Integer instead of String for elem
2. Replace `int[] arry = new int[siz];` with Integer[]  arry = new Integer[siz];

Hence code will become:

```
        Integer[]  arry = new Integer[siz];

        List<Integer> arrycoll = Arrays.asList(arry);
        for (Integer elem : arrycoll) {
            System.out.println(elem);
        }
```

Comment: That wont work because `Arrays.asList(arry);` still return a List of this type: `List<int[]>`

Comment: yup. this works out.. thank you.. But I cant make yours as accepted becuase Elliott posted the answer first..

Comment: Not a problem, Welcome.

Answer (score 0):

For print purpose only, simply try like this; casting as `int[]`

```
List arrycoll = Arrays.asList(arry);
for (Object elem : arrycoll) {

    int[] iArr1 = (int[]) elem;     
    for (int i : iArr1) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```